# How to select all nested input siblings in Jquery onclick first element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to Checks all input those are inside labels on click "check-all" class. I have tried by nextAll() method but it's not working. kindly help

```js
$('.check-all').click(function() {
  alert('asdasd');
  $(this).nextAll('input').prop('checked', 'true');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle-check-group">
  <a><img src="img/select_all.png" class="check-all" /></a>
  <label class="switch">
             <input type="checkbox" class="myinput" />
             <span class="slider">Ankit</span>
          </label>
  <label class="switch">
             <input type="checkbox"/>
             <span class="slider">Mohal</span>
          </label>
  <label class="switch">
             <input type="checkbox"/>
             <span class="slider">Kamal</span>
          </label>
</div>

<div class="toggle-check-group">
  <a><img src="img/select_all.png" class="check-all" /></a>
  <label class="switch">
             <input type="checkbox" class="myinput" />
             <span class="slider">Ankit</span>
          </label>
  <label class="switch">
             <input type="checkbox"/>
             <span class="slider">Mohal</span>
          </label>
  <label class="switch">
             <input type="checkbox"/>
             <span class="slider">Kamal</span>
          </label>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to use `parents("a")` or `parent()` then use `nextAll()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can :

- use closest method to get closest parent of check-all with class
  toggle-check-group
- use find method to get all input child of toggle-check-group

if you want to check/uncheck all check bow with the .check-all elements

an idea can be to store the checked state of the first check box and apply it to all sibling ones

```
var isCheck = inputs.first().prop('checked');
```

```js
$('.check-all').click(function() {
  var inputs = $(this).closest('.toggle-check-group').find('input');
  var isCheck = inputs.first().prop('checked');
  inputs.prop('checked', !isCheck);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle-check-group">
  <a><img src="img/select_all.png" class="check-all" /></a>
  <label class="switch">
                 <input type="checkbox" class="myinput" />
                 <span class="slider">Ankit</span>
              </label>
  <label class="switch">
                 <input type="checkbox"/>
                 <span class="slider">Mohal</span>
              </label>
  <label class="switch">
                 <input type="checkbox"/>
                 <span class="slider">Kamal</span>
              </label>
</div>

<div class="toggle-check-group">
  <a><img src="img/select_all.png" class="check-all" /></a>
  <label class="switch">
                 <input type="checkbox" class="myinput" />
                 <span class="slider">Ankit</span>
              </label>
  <label class="switch">
                 <input type="checkbox"/>
                 <span class="slider">Mohal</span>
              </label>
  <label class="switch">
                 <input type="checkbox"/>
                 <span class="slider">Kamal</span>
              </label>
</div>
```